# Do you know how to render textures with the camera?

Tags: rendering, texturing, baking

So I saw a video tutorial on Youtube entitled “Modelling Building in Blender Part 2”. I’ll link it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXMOtcYtDWM

So around the 6:15 mark, the person in the video did this think where he rendered part of the air vent with the camera and then use it as a texture for the air vent; reducing the poly count. I want to do something similar as a means of making textures but, he doesn’t properly explain what he’s doing. Could you explain what he’s doing or point to another tutorial that’s shorter and focuses primary on that technique( I’d prefer something shorter since I got ADHD). He did sometime similar for the rails of the fire escape but, he also made the background transparent. Can anyone explain how he does it so I can do something similar myself?

Comment: He said use MatCap. I found this under this name: https://youtu.be/oly17M9eYfk

Comment: Thanks.I know that this might be slightly off topic but, the reasoning why I’m interesting in this topic is because I’m making a 3d game in the Godot engine( more specifically Godot 3.5) and I’m making textures for my own gaming asset. I’m not sure if the material will still work in the Godot engine, with the normal map node. What would I have to do to make everything more game ready?